# Protection against path manipulation and manipulated executables

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have a couple of tools that are initialized as a process by my .NET application. Some of them are from third parties. The list of tools to start is configurable. I want to protect the system against executing (maliciously) modified tools.

**Assumption and possible attack vectors**

I assume my application is protected by the operating system, including its configuration file. The folders containing the tools to be started are *not* though. Meaning an attacker could theoretically replace any of the tools with a different program bearing the same name.

**Possible solution**

My current concept would be to add SHA256 hashes of each tool to the config. This should prevent them from being replaced by manipulated applications, assuming my application and the configuration file containing the list is protected.

**Implementation example**

Config file example:

```
 <FileHashes>
    <Hashes>
      <add Filename="the-tool.exe" Hash="87BC21C157F7B3E4..." />
    </Hashes>
  </FileHashes>
```

Application example:

```
public void Execute(FileInfo fileToLoad)
{           
    var hashDictionary = LoadHashDictionary();  //load hash from config          
    if (!hashDictionary.TryGetValue(fileToLoad.Name, out string configFileHash))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unknown file");
    }

    var fileHash = GetFileHash(fileToLoad);
    if (!configFileHash.ToUpperInvariant().Equals(fileHash))
    {
        throw new Exception("File is manipulated");
    }

    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = fileToLoad.FullName
    });
}

public string GetFileHash(FileInfo fileToLoad)
{            
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileToLoad.FullName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var shaHash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            fileStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] hasValue = shaHash.ComputeHash(fileStream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hasValue)
                               .Replace("-", string.Empty)
                               .ToUpperInvariant();
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- Are there better ways to protect against manipulated files on application level?
- Assuming the configuration file isn't safe, as it is also placed in a folder that can theoretically be accessed by an attacker. Where could I place the application whitelist and the hashes?

Comment: Why assume an attacker cannot manipulate your application to bypass the checks, but *can* replace other executables at will? It seems to me that any one mechanism you'd use to protect one should be used to protect the other (and the favored mechanism for that would of course be file access control).

Comment: I assume my application and its configuration file cannot be manipulated (e.g. protected by OS access rights), but the folder with the tools don't share the same protection level. Worst case they are on a share accessible by anyone. I've modified my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

As you said. Confg file isn't safe either. Malicious application can modify your tools + config files all together to mask itself.

Whats an easy way to prevent this? Code signing.

Simply sign all your tools and do a certificate verification before you start your tool from main app.

Comment: And what would keep a malicious tool or user from replacing the certificate used for verification, or adding a new trusted one?

Comment: So don't get me wrong, code signing is still a good option, but it's not the silver bullet, and my point is if the malicious user has enough privileges to get around all the protections that can be put around for example the config file or the application binaries, then he probably can change application binaries and/or the trusted certificates too. So as always, the question is what threat the asker is protecting against, and who the threat actor is.

Comment: @GaborLengyel you should be the only one with the certificate private key. That's the whole idea of cert signing. The cert itself is not present at the user's machine so malicious user can never replace it unless he/she some how got a hold of your private key

Comment: Yes, but the public key is used to verify the signature, stored where you want to verify. If I can replace the public key, or add one to the trusted list, I can sign a rogue binary with my own key, and it will still be verifiable. Adding a certificate to the cert store might (or might not) need an admin, but access to the application binaries or the config holding the pub key reference can also be locked down to an admin. What would provide help is something like an HSM, but for most applications that's far fetched.

Comment: @GaborLengyel no you don't. The public key is stored on CA and will be verified by Windows. Unless the malicious user is able to modify Windows kernel code then that's another story. All you have to do is to verify the file against a CA and check to see the signer's name is you.

Comment: You are wrong. On Windows, start certmgr.msc. :) There's a list of trusted certificates, as in any other operating system. As an admin, I can add any certificate to the trusted list as a root cert ("create my own CA" if you like) and then any certificate I issue will be trusted on that machine.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I stand corrected. Your digital signature will tell Windows about which CA the cert was issued from and Windows will verify that it was actually signed by that CA and its valid. Sure you can add your own CA and cert if you like but Windows won't check with your own CA for the cert that's signed by some other CA. You can sign the malicious tool using your fake cert and add it to the store but you can't fake it as one signed by the public CA which you got the cert from.

Comment: Exactly, but you don't need to, that's the point. The signature can be trusted and the malicious binary can be run by adding a malicious cert to the trusted store - it doesn't need to look like it was signed by a real CA, which indeed would not be possible. So back to the original point, while there is a solution to this (HSMs), simply signing the code is not the holy grail - while still being a good thing of course.

Comment: @GaborLengyel you are still missing the point. Sure you can make an application look like safe to run but YOUR .net application will be doing the cert verification. So as long as your .net application did not get modified you can make sure that the tools that you started are not from malicious source. But if you are wondering if you can protect your .net program from being replaced by someone else then the answer is no you can't

Comment: How would I go about validating the certificates of tools called by my application? Some of these tools are third party.

Comment: @Greg X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile and X509Certificate.Verify. If its not signed then you are out of luck